# What is wrong with my following code

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing coin change algorithm. Algorithm is taken from http://ace.cs.ohiou.edu/~razvan/courses/cs404/lecture19.pdf

Following is my code till now:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int compute_change(std::vector<int> &d, int n) {
    int k = (int)d.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > C(k, std::vector<int>(n + 1));
    for ( int i = 0; i < k ; i++) 
        C[i][0]  = 0;   
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n ; i++) 
        C[0][i]  = i;

    for ( int i = 1 ; i < k; i++) {
        for ( int j = 1 ; j <= n; j++) {
            if ( j < d[i] ) 
                C[i][j] = C[i - 1][j];
            else
                C[i][j] = std::min(C[i - 1][j], 1 + C[i][j - d[i]]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << C[k - 1 ][n - 1] << std::endl;
    return C[k - 1][n - 1];
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    int points[] = {2, 3, 17, 23, 42, 98};
    std::vector<int> d (points, points + sizeof(points) / sizeof(int));

    int solution =  compute_change(d,2349 );
    solution     =  compute_change(d,2102 );
    solution     =  compute_change(d,2001 );
    solution     =  compute_change(d,1747 );

    return 0;
}
```

For input `2349` and `2102` answer is correct but for `2001` answer is incorrect.
I am not able to find the bug here.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? It has a bug in it. Debugging is an important skill that you should be building.

Comment: What is wrong with it? You wrote in such a way that after writing it neither you nor we can understand it.

Comment: If you can't form a question exemplifying the problematic behavior and giving examples of what you've found you need to debug more.

Comment: So, what are the correct answers and the incorrect answer for 2001?  Don't withhold information like that.

Comment: The ++ should be replaced with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up the 0-based indexes of C++ arrays vs 1-based indexing used in the algorithm. That is, `d[1]` in the algorithm is `d[0]` for this code. But in a few places you also used 0 based indexes. You may want to double check all array indexes.